# IntelliJ freeze at start: org.h2.mvstore.MVStoreException: File corrupted in chunk

Tags: intellij-idea, freeze, startup

Starting IDEA freezes at Splashscreen.

- Restarting does not help
- reinstall does not help
- deleting caches does not help

Log file states:

```
2023-06-29 10:47:42,492 [   2337] SEVERE - #c.i.o.a.i.FlushQueue - File corrupted in chunk 29, expected page length 4..384, got 11336 [2.2.219/6]
org.h2.mvstore.MVStoreException: File corrupted in chunk 29, expected page length 4..384, got 11336 [2.2.219/6]
    at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newMVStoreException(DataUtils.java:996)
    at org.h2.mvstore.Page.read(Page.java:590)
```

Problem also apears on Intellij Youtrack page: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-317697
but no working solution is given (at least for me).

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by

1. Kill your running IntelliJ in Windows 'Task manager', or equivalent.
2. rename your Intellij Settings Folder '.IntelliJIdea' to '.IntelliJIdea_backup'
3. Start Intellij
4. Popup Sreen asks for "import Setting", shoose to import settings and point to your backup folder '.IntelliJIdea_backup'
5. It should start up normally with all your settings